# neo4j cypher keep ordering imposed by path for later in the query

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am using a query like

```
MATCH p=((:Start)-[:NEXT*..100]->(n))
WHERE ALL(node IN nodes(p) WHERE ...)
WITH DISTINCT n WHERE (n:RELEVANT)
...
RETURN n.someprop;
```

Where I want to have the results ordered by the natural ordering arising from the direction of the `-[:NEXT]->` relationships.
But the `WITH` in the third line scrambles up that ordering. Problem is, I need the with to 1. filter for `:RELEVANT` nodes and 2. to get only distinct such nodes.

Is there some way to preserve the ordering? Maybe assign number ordering on the path and reuse it later with `ORDER BY`? No idea how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're asking for distinct nodes, which indicates that the node might be reachable by multiple paths, and thus might be present at multiple distances from the start node.

Instead of using DISTINCT, you should use `min()` (or `max()`, depending on your requirements) on the path length for each `n`. Since those are aggregation functions, you will only ever get a single row for each `n`.

```
MATCH p=((:Start)-[:NEXT*..100]->(n:RELEVANT))
WHERE ALL(node IN nodes(p) WHERE ...)
WITH n, min(length(p)) as distance
WITH n 
ORDER BY distance
...
RETURN n.someprop;
```

Comment: Thank you! I had to extend it like `max(length(filter(mnode IN nodes(p) WHERE (mnode:RELEVANT))))` and it does exactly what I wanted!

Answer (score 1):

And if you remove the `WHERE` clause from `WITH` and put the label `:RELEVANT` in the `MATCH`? Maybe the `WHERE` is causing the problem...  Try something this:

```
MATCH p=((:Start)-[:NEXT*..100]->(n:RELEVANT))
WHERE ALL(node IN nodes(p) WHERE ...)
WITH DISTINCT n
...
RETURN n.someprop;
```

Comment: problem with that approach is: there is no connected path between `:RELEVANT` nodes. I need to match non-`:RELEVANT`-nodes as well and then filter the relevant ones afterwards

Comment: @tscherg I had placed `:RELEVANT` in the `(:Start)` node instead of `(n)`. I edited the answer. Now make sense?

Comment: That seems possible! I was always under the impression that when I put the `:RELEVANT` label in the `n` node like that, I can't get to nodes where there is no path of only `:RELEVANT` nodes. I was wrong, it's possible! Thanks!

Comment: @tscherg you are welcome! If this answer solve your question remember to [accept it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/360570) to inform another user that your question is solved and help future viewers of your question. Thanks!

Comment: What is still unanswered for me: how do I get the distinct `:RELEVANT` nodes and in the same order as in the path? Strangely enough, the query you suggested exactly *reverts* the ordering (i.e. makes 3,2,1 out of 1,2,3)